# The pattern name for "instance variable to local variable"

Tags: c#, design-patterns

This coding pattern "instance variable to local variable" is often useful for simple thread safety.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; } = 42;

    public ReturnValue UseSomeNumber(...)
    {
        int someNumberCopy = this.SomeNumber;
        if (someNumberCopy > ...)
        {
            // ... do some work with someNumberCopy
        }
        else
        {
            // ... do something else with someNumberCopy
        }
    }
}
```

(Excerpted from [C# Copying instance variable to local variable in functions of same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645608/c-sharp-copying-instance-variable-to-local-variable-in-functions-of-same-class), modified private field to public property.)

Does this pattern have a short name?

I think it's hard to understand at a glance without any comments, but also hard to write explanatory comments on all of the occurrences of this pattern.

I just want to write the name of the pattern to say "Google it", but I couldn't find any appropriate simple word.

Comment: I would worry if I saw that too often in a code-base. It's even harder to understand if the person reading the code doesn't fully understand reference vs value types (which is not uncommon) and then asks you why their code doesn't work like this example

Comment: This is a form of thread caching, and really isn't the best way to share data across multiple threads. It guarantees that the value doesn't change while running the method by some other thread. The issue here is that you don't know exactly how "up to date" the value is when you get it, it may come from your local processor core cache, or memory, who knows.

Comment: Umm, yes, this might have some good and bad points. In order to avoid explaining them in code comments, I think it'd be helpful to google it if it has a name.

Comment: Actually you are not referring a GoF design pattern, nor any other design pattern. In fact it is a coding pattern. It is just a coding trick to encounter thread safety issues.If you want to find a title for this trick, maybe you can find something in this search: c# thread safety coding tricks