# Why does List<T>'s MoveNext() implementation use a localList?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I read the implementation for [MoveNext()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1159) in `List<T>`:

```
public bool MoveNext() {
    List<T> localList = list;
 
    if (version == localList._version && ((uint)index < (uint)localList._size)) 
    {                                                     
        current = localList._items[index];                    
        index++;
        return true;
    }
    return MoveNextRare();
}
```

What is the point of copying the reference to `list` into the local var `localList`?

If they are both pointing to the same object, why can't you replace all instances of `localList` with `list`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Copying instance variable to local variable in functions of same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645608/c-sharp-copying-instance-variable-to-local-variable-in-functions-of-same-class)

Comment: @silkfire None of those answers apply to this question

Comment: It's probably a profiler-driven micro-optimization. Accessing a field is probably a tiny bit slower than accessing a local variable. The fact that they've written a private `MoveNextRare` method which is only called in one place and returns a constant value suggests someone was micro-optimizing this specific case, to affect the exact instructions that the JIT emits

Comment: First of all it's implementation details, you should learn from books and not from some undocumented code you got access to. If you look further there is a throw when comparing if `version` has changed, you need to figure out what is it first, how it can change and why.

Comment: @Sinatr Reading the BCL is a fine way to learn about all sorts of odd corners of C# and .NET. Asking about strange things you find is a great way of improving your knowledge

Comment: @Sinatr learning the implementation details of a language is a fantastic way to develop an intimate knowledge of the language. Do you think the genius people who create programming languages have the attitude of "it's just implementation details"?

Comment: @Sinatr I can see how there is a throw when comparing to version, but I don't see how that's relevant. You could use list for that too since they are pointing to the same object.

Comment: @silkfire that doesn't answer my question because that only applies to value types, not reference types.

Comment: @canton7, when you have an issue then looking at source is justified. Trying to understand implementation details is a more time consuming (ineffective) way to learn, given the amount of availabe and ready for consuming knowledge. Like I said, go figure out what is `version` first (I believe it's releated, I could be wrong). The field is not marked as `readonly` either. Is the value expected to be changed? Maybe it was in earlier/different implementation?

Comment: @Sinatr You're speaking to someone who has learned a lot from reading the BCL -- beyond a certain point, you run out of books and blogs to read. I found it effective, and I'm not sure what basis you have to claim that it's ineffective. `version` isn't related, that should be fairly clear. The field became `readonly` in .NET Core. It's obvious that method has been micro-optimized, see my earlier comments

Comment: @canton7, this question is a demonstration why this method to learn is ineffective. Not only you who learned a lot didn't answer, noone yet did. In my opinion such questions as a whole type of questions "why this guy wrote this code" should not be asked or guessed.

Comment: @Sinatr I gave an educated guess in the comments, and FrankPI said the same thing in an answer. So OP did get an answer, and likely the correct one; probably learnt something in the process as well. Are you saying that people should only ask questions that other people know the answer to? How does someone know ahead of time whether anyone's going to know the answer to their question?

Comment: @Sinatr as another example, [this is one of my favourite lines in the BCL](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,551). Spotting that when reading the class out of curiosity, and asking *why* that test was there (this was back before the comment was there), taught me a lot about .NET which I might not otherwise have learned.

Comment: @Sinatr I guarantee you, the experts in this field, the ones who go and create the next most popular programming language, these people would have dug deeper, to get that intimate deep knowledge of how things work. Have you heard of leaky abstractions before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably that is a performance issue. Access to local variables is slightly faster than access to instance variables. And - as `List` is probably one of the most used classes in the CLR - having good performance matters.

Local variables can directly be read from stack or maybe a register, while instance variables read the address of the object, and then get the value relative to that.

Comment: "Access to local variables is slightly faster than access to instance variables." Why is that? Could you provide some info on this? I'm curious.

Comment: @nilsK Local variable access is a straight load from a fixed stack address. `object.field` requires an extra pointer deref.